# How to setup kubernetes nginx ingress without load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to create an nginx-ingress for my 2 services without LB. First, I create `nginx_ingress.yaml`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
---
```

And then `echo_ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: subdomain1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: subdomain2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo2
          servicePort: 80
```

But, when ingress was created, it doesn't show its address and it seems not running properly, I cannot get anything from port 80 on `curl`:

```
NAME           HOSTS                                  ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
echo-ingress   git.satelkom.co.id,op.satelkom.co.id             80      8m9s
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: It would be better if you provide enough info for your question i.e. what you did to set everything up, what you got, what is your error or problems etc. Then it is easy to answer to your question.

Comment: Shudipta is right, we need some more information. Where is this cluster (AWS, GKE, on-premise)? Also any more steps you have done? You mention ingress controller, did you deploy it at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to define path ?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: subdomain1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /   # <--- Add this tag
  - host: subdomain2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /   # <--- Add this tag
```

Or define external IPs on ingress service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalIPs:    # <-- Try to add this 2 lines
    - <YOUR IP LAN or WAN>
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http # <-- Replace by port number: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https # <-- Replace by port number: 443
```

Comment: Still not working. Should I deploy ingress nginx controller first?

Comment: Order is not important because k8s restart failed pod.I don't know about nginx ingress, I use [haproxy ingress](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress). Do you have all pods running ? copy/paste the `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` output